# Will this regex be slow? Is there any way to optimize it?

Tags: javascript, regex

This will be run in javascript multiple times on bits of HTML. Will all of the or expressions make it slow? Can it be optimized?

```
\<[^\>]*?(abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|article|aside|audio|base|basefont|bdi|bdo|big|blockquote|body|button|canvas|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|command|datalist|dd|del|details|dfn|dialog|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|font|footer|form|frame|frameset|head|header|hr|html|iframe|img|input|ins|kbd|keygen|label|legend|link|map|mark|menu|meta|meter|nav|noframes|noscript|object|optgroup|option|output|param|pre|progress|q|rp|rt|ruby|samp|script|section|select|small|source|strike|style|sub|summary|sup|textarea|time|title|track|tt|var|video|wbr)[^\>]*?\>/g
```

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not run some tests yourself? You'll likely get more accurate results that way.

Comment: Aside from not parsing HTML with regex (as somebody will no doubt post), it's impossible to tell if it's a problem out-of-context. If you call it once, it's probably not even worth worrying about, if you call it a million times in a tight loop, then maybe you should. Your need to profile your code and identify the bottlenecks.

Comment: If you want it to be a magnitude faster, use string functions and not regex... but if it doesn't need to be faster, leave it as it is. You can use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) to measure the speed of various methods in different browsers, with many samples.

Comment: I don't know about fast or slow, but it sure is ugly.

Comment: Also, your regex will be broken the first time in encounters an `<IFRAME>`, `<Iframe>` or `<iFrAmE>`. Your regex needs to be case-insensitive. Or better yet, parse HTML properly.

Comment: Good point Matt, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try moving element names found **very** frequently in your source (`a`, `div`) to the front of the list:

```
… (a|div|abbr| …
```

Also, I think your pattern will match, e.g., `< notanabbreviation >`. If that's not what you want, try

```
<\b(a|abbr|…)\b[^>]*?>
```

The `\b` preceding the alternations helps because it lets the engine exit early without trying all of the alternations.

But you just have to test to see. I made a [jsperf test using nytimes.com](https://jsperf.com/html-regex-purrformance) as an example.

[image: Test results]

Comment: Thanks, thing is if I use \b(div|blah)\b[^>]*?> then won't it not match <div> because the angle brackets are joined on to the tag name and do not satisfy the word boundry operator?

Comment: @JoeNFU No, `\b` matches the boundary between a word character and nonword character, e.g., `<a` `>a` `a<` `a>` each have a word boundary between the first and second character.

Comment: Ah I see, I was having issues with leading slashes but thats fixed now. Thanks again, if I could up vote you twice I would :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this tool](http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/regex-tester.html) to compare different regex

it took 2.4 seconds to execute over the source code of Yahoo's front page . This is not a scientific test but it doesnt look very effecient.

PS silverlight plugin is required

Comment: Is Silverlight or Javascript running the regexen?

Answer (score 0):

adding i after the g will make it case insensitive

also since it is javascript maybe you could use a hash instead of a giant regex